# MS Access Query - Count using most recent inquiries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am still new to this Access and am not sure how to do this. I have this prospective customer table: 
my table and the expected result:
[image]

Or here is the data, not sure if it will show correctly:

```
ID  Dates   Status
1   12-Sep-15   Follow up
1   2-Jan-15    Request
1   15-Apr-14   Letter
2   1-Sep-15    Request
2   1-Apr-15    Letter
3   12-Dec-15   Follow up
3   11-Sep-14   Request
3   12-Mar-14   Letter
4   14-Jan-16   Letter
4   12-Dec-15   Email
5   12-Jan-16   Letter
5   1 Des 2015  Email
```

And the result would be like this:

```
    Follow up 2
    Request 1
    Letter 2
```

I first tried this SQL:

```
SELECT id, status, Max(dates) AS TEST
FROM Sample
GROUP BY id, status;
```

which still would give me the original table. I was hoping it would return the id and status for most recent dates.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you very much !!

Comment: Could you explain the result in a bit more detail, for example where you're getting "2" from in "Letter"?

Comment: Hi Joachim. For each customer ID, I would need to pick the most recent date to summarize the status. In this case, 'Follow Up' is the most recent status for customer ID 1 and 3, 'Letter' is the most recent status for customer ID 4 and 5 - hence they both have 2 counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want id and status for the latest date, then you need to use a subselect to get the max dates by id and join your table on it by id and date:

```
SELECT s.id, s.status, t.maxdate
FROM status as s
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id, Max(dates) AS maxdate
FROM Sample
GROUP BY id) as t ON t.id=s.id and t.maxdate=s.dates
```

Comment: Thanks, Shadow ! It works - except the 'status' in FROM (line 2) will need to be changed to Sample. I am learning more and more now how to construct this now !